# How do I add WCF client endpoints programmatically?

Tags: wcf

I need my service to consume other services, and I need to configure these dependencies in code. How do I do this?

This is very simple in config via the following (example):

```
   <client>
  <endpoint name="registerService"
            address="http://127.0.0.1/registration/" binding="basicHttpBinding"    
            contract="*"/>
  </client>
```

But for some reason finding the code equivalent is not as easy as I thought it'd be.

Comment: are you using a generated proxy ("Add service reference..."), or instantiating directly against a contract?

Comment: No generated proxy. I'm actually using this from the RoutingService (new to WCF 4) which I need to configure via code. But this detail shouldn't impact too much right?

Answer (score 9):

If you're using the Visual Studio generated proxy (via "Add Service Reference..."), then you're using the `ClientBase` abstract class & you'll have a number of constructors that allow you to pass in a config section, an endpoint, a binding etc.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576141.aspx

And if you're instantiating a ChannelFactory then you again have a number of constructors to use.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576132.aspx

```
// create bindings & endpoints
var binding = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding();
var endpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost/MyService.svc");

var factory = new ChannelFactory<IMyService>(binding, endpoint);

var channel = factory.CreateChannel();
// then call your operations...
channel.MyOperation();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but neither of these help. I may need to edit my question to be more specific -- I'm operating in the context of a service which in turn consumes other services. I want to add those dependencies programmatically to the WCF infrastructure.