# WCF Client Wrapper

Tags: c#, wcf, client, wrapper

I have a service and I need to communicate with it so I started investigating WCF. I setup the service to listen and created a client. All communication is working fine.

The service will be used by several customers. Instead of having them setup a client and go through the WCF learning curve I figured I would just wrap the client and hide all the WCF implementation. I found that inorder to get this to work they still have to include in their app.config file the service model with endpoint information.

Is there a way to completely hide the service model information? I would prefer them to simply reference my dll and start making calls. It seems unnecessary for libraries beyond my client to have to know about endpoint information.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create the endpoint programmatically rather than through configuration, as in the example shown in the answer to this SO question: [How do I add WCF client endpoints programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118221/how-do-i-add-wcf-client-endpoints-programmatically)

Comment: This just moves from config to code. I want to hide all WCF implementation from the customer, so all they have to do is reference my dll, create an instance of my client wrapper, and call a method. Within the client wrapper is where I want to handle all the binding and address WCF specifics (and I am happy leaving it in the app.config or web.config file). Thanks.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that the consumer of your code be required to programmatically set up the endpoint themselves. I think you should do that inside the constructor of your custom client. Then you can instantiate a WCF channel as in the example and delegate to it all calls to the client.

Comment: I dug a little deeper after your replay and was able to get it to work, thanks! When I originally replied I tried to create the client and wrapper all in one dll. This did not work. I then broke the client wrapper into a 3rd project and created the channel there and everything works! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to have wcf client settings inside your web config you will need to create settings using code. Here is sample code how to create instance to wcf client (in this case using BasicHttpBinding) without web.config:

```
    BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(); 
    EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("http://someServer/DemoWcfService");         
    TestServiceClient client = new TestServiceClient(binding, address)
```

But I would suggest you to stay with web.config wcf client configuration because it's easy to reconfigure.

Comment: Same as luksan's answer, see reply. Thanks.