# How can I use extern alias in web.config?

Tags: wcf, .net-assembly, extern

I'm new to WCF and I'm trying to use a contract defined externally in my code. The issue is that my code, as well as the external code have 2 conflicts with the same class name within the same namespace. I added the external nuget, and specified it's alias in References in Visual Studio to resolve the conflicts. In the C# file, I'm able to use it with extern alias, as below -

```
extern alias X;
using X.IT.Contracts;
```

However, the contract also has to be used in web.config. The below two ways are not working -

```
<endpoint address="net.pipe://localhost/XYZ.svc" binding="netNamedPipeBinding" contract="IT.Contracts.Service.IXService" behaviorConfiguration="InterceptorBehavior" />

<endpoint address="net.pipe://localhost/XYZ.svc" binding="netNamedPipeBinding" contract="X.IT.Contracts.Service.IXService" behaviorConfiguration="InterceptorBehavior" />
```

Is there a way to specify the alias for an assembly in the web.config file?

Comment: As a workaround, maybe you could write  specify your contarct in code , please refer to  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118221/how-do-i-add-wcf-client-endpoints-programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118221/how-do-i-add-wcf-client-endpoints-programmatically)